# org-mode function definition is void

Tags: org-mode, use-package

I install org-mode using use-package via the orgmode.org elpa archive.

In the past month I've received `Symbol’s function definition is void` messages such as:

```
org-capture-select-template: Symbol’s function definition is void: org-mks

org-archive-subtree: Symbol’s function definition is void: org-show-all
```

These functions seems to be defined in `org.el` and `org-macs.el` respectively.

I've tried deleting my `~/.emacs.d/elpa` folder and reinstalling everything, but still get the error.

Here's my use-package macro for org. Any advice appreciated.

```
  (require 'package)
  (setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
               ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
               ("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/")))
  (setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
  (package-initialize)

 (use-package org
:ensure t
:pin "org"
:custom
(org-agenda-files (list (expand-file-name "~/Documents/org-mode/work.org")
                        (expand-file-name "~/Documents/org-mode/XXXX.org")
                        (expand-file-name "~/Documents/org-mode/XXXX.org")
                        (expand-file-name "~/Documents/org-mode/XXXX.org")))
(org-default-notes-file (expand-file-name "~/Documents/org-mode/notes.org"))
(org-hide-leading-stars t)
(org-startup-indented t)
(org-catch-invisible-edits 'smart)
(org-fontify-whole-heading-line t)
(org-context-in-file-links t)
(org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)
(org-src-fontify-natively t)
(org-src-tab-acts-natively t)
(org-enforce-todo-dependencies t)
(org-log-into-drawer t)
(org-hide-emphasis-markers t)
(org-todo-keywords '((sequence "TODO(t/!)"
                               "IN-PROGRESS(p/!)"
                               "WAITING ON CUSTOMER(w@/@)"
                               "SUBMITTED FOR REVIEW(r@/@)"
                               "SUBMITTED FOR QA(q/!)"
                               "SUBMITTED FOR RELEASE(b@/!)"
                               "ASSIGNED(s@/!)"
                               "|"
                               "ON-HOLD(h/@)"
                               "DONE(d/!)"
                               "CANCELLED(c/@)"
                               "CLOSED(l/@)"
                               "NOT A BUG(n/@)"
                               "DUPLICATE BUG(u@/!)"
                               "DELIVERED(v/!)"
                               "PR ACCEPTED(a@/!)"
                               )))

(org-capture-templates '(("o" "XXX")
                         ("ob" "Bugs" entry
                          (file+headline "/home/laurence/Documents/org-mode/XXX.org" "Bugs")
                          "* TODO %^L %^C %^g %?")
                         ("oe" "Enhancement" entry
                          (file+headline "/home/laurence/Documents/org-mode/XXX.org" "Enhancements")
                          "* TODO %^L %^C %^g %?")

                         ("s" "XXX")
                         ("se" "Enhancement Requests")
                         ("sec" "Customer enhancement" entry
                          (file+headline "/home/laurence/Documents/org-mode/XXX.org" "Customer ERs")
                          "* TODO %^L %^C %^g %?")
                         ("sei" "Internal enhancement" entry
                          (file+headline "/home/laurence/Documents/org-mode/XXX.org" "Internal ERs")
                          "* TODO %^L %^C %^g %?")
                         ("sb" "Bugs")
                         ("sbc" "Customer bugs" entry
                          (file+headline "/home/laurence/Documents/org-mode/XXX.org" "Customer Bugs")
                          "* TODO %^L %^C %^g %?")
                         ("sbi" "Internal bugs" entry
                          (file+headline "/home/laurence/Documents/org-mode/XXX.org" "Internal Bugs")
                          "* TODO %^L %^C %^g %?")
                         ("sby" "XXX's bugs" entry
                          (file+headline "/home/laurence/Documents/org-mode/XXX.org" "XXX's Bugs")
                          "* TODO %^L %^C %^g %?")

                         ("u" "XXX")
                         ("ub" "Bugs" entry
                          (file+headline "/home/laurence/Documents/org-mode/XXX.org" "Bugs")
                          "* TODO %^L %^C %^g %?")
                         ("ue" "Enhancement" entry
                          (file+headline "/home/laurence/Documents/org-mode/XXX.org" "Enhancements")
                          "* TODO %^L %^C %^g %?")))

:bind
("C-c s" . org-custom-sort-parent-by-todo-order)
("C-c l" . org-store-link)
("C-c c" . org-capture)
("C-c a" . org-agenda)
("C-c b" . org-iswitchb)
("C-c c" . org-capture)
:hook
(org-mode . (lambda () (add-hook 'before-save-hook (lambda () (org-update-statistics-cookies t)) nil t)))
:init
(defun org-custom-sort-parent-by-todo-order ()
  (interactive)
  (outline-up-heading 1)
  (org-sort-entries nil ?o)
  (org-sort-entries nil ?n)
  (org-cycle)
  (org-cycle))
:config
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((shell      . t)
   (emacs-lisp . t)
   (python     . t)
   (sql . t))))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org-mode function definition is void](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51909/org-mode-function-definition-is-void)

Comment: Seems to have posted twice. I was getting errors

Comment: Other post deleted now

Comment: try with this `(use-package org
 :pin org
  :ensure org-plus-contrib ...`